# C++ template metaprogramming (version less than 17, preferably 11)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming

I have some C++ and std library experience, and have even written a couple of simple templated functions but - like many others, it seems - template metaprogramming fries my brain.

I want to produce a templated function that parses a std::string for a small range of legal values. It needs to return a different type depending on what is found in the string or an error code if the string does not match any of the legal forms. For example valid string could be:

- a) numeric single value e.g. "42"
- b) single non-numeric string e.g. "anything"
- c) comma-separated list of a) e.g. "13,42,666"
- d) comma-separated list of b) e.g. "anything,you,want"

Different instantiations would "expect" a certain type and produce an error on a failed match, for example if I want c) and find an otherwise-valid d) then: error, and vice versa. Obviously when a valid match is found, the return type will be different for each.

I'm thinking the return value should be a `pair<uint32_t errorcode,T>` where T is:

- a) `uint32_t`
- b) `std::string`
- c) `std::vector<uint32_t>`
- d) `std::vector<std::string>`

At the highest level of abstraction what I want to do is:

instantiation 1:

if(expecting numeric && (number or list_of_numbers)) f( n | n1,n2,n3...) 
else error

instantiation 2:

if(expecting string && (string or list_of_strings)) f( s | s1,s2,s3...) 
else error

I think I'm going to need `#include <type_traits>` and probably std::is_arithmetic but I just cant "get" the concept and syntax of getting the template to "branch" depending on whether the Expected type is numeric.

Getting more concrete, I'm  starting with something like:

```
template<typename ReturnType, typename Expected>
pair<uint32_t,ReturnType> parseInput(std::string input,std::function<void(ReturnType)> f){
    if(!initalvalidation(input)) return std::make_pair<999, ? >; // Exclude total garbage... ? = don't care as long as its a valid ReturnType

    /*compile-time-if ?? */  *if* is_numeric(Expected){
        ReturnType result;
        result=parseInputForNumbers(input); // will return an empty ReturnType if invalid
        return make_pair<(result.size() > 0 ? 0:123),result>; // 123 = bad numeric format
        // obvs that won't work for uint32_t as it has no size() function, so again...HOW?
    }
    else {
        ... similar for strings
    }
}
```

I know it isn't going to look like an if / else block , but that's the only way I can explain it!

Finally, I don't need help with parsing, how to decide at runtime whether something is numeric etc. I only want help and advice regarding the structure / syntax of the template function.

Comment: you cant choose the return type at runtime

Comment: can you show an example of how you would call the function?

Comment: What would `pair` look like if there has been an error? And where is `f` used?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the point of template here:
How about some other ideas?

You might have:

```
enum class Error; // Or dedicated class or use std::optional

std::variant<std::uint32_t, Error> ParseUInt32(const std::string& s);
std::variant<std::string, Error> ParseString(const std::string& s);
std::variant<std::vector<std::uint32_t>, Error> ParseUInt32s(const std::string& s);
std::variant<std::vector<std::string>, Error> ParseStrings(const std::string& s);
```

If you want have same name for simplify template code, you might add overloads:

```
template <typename T> struct Tag {};

auto Parse(Tag<std::uint32>, const std::string& s) { return ParseUInt32(s); }
auto Parse(Tag<std::string>, const std::string& s) { return ParseString(s); }
auto Parse(Tag<std::vector<std::uint32_t>>, const std::string& s) { return ParseUInt32s(s); }
auto Parse(Tag<std::vector<std::string>>, const std::string& s) { return ParseStrings(s); }
```

And, so, you might have a "generic" one:

```
std::variant<std::uint32_t,
             std::string,
             std::vector<std::uint32_t>,
             std::vector<std::string>,
             Error>
Parse(const std::string& s)
{
    auto v1 = ParseUInt32s(s);
    if (auto* res = std::get_if<std::vector<std::uint32_t>>(v1)) {
        return std::move(*res);
    }

    auto v2 = ParseStrings(s);
    if (auto* res = std::get_if<std::vector<std::string>>(v2)) {
        return std::move(*res);
    }

    auto v3 = ParseUInt32(s);
    if (auto* res = std::get_if<std::uint32_t>(v3)) {
        return *res;
    }

    auto v4 = ParseString(s);
    if (auto* res = std::get_if<std::string>(v4)) {
        return std::move(*res);
    }
    return Error::InvalidInput;
}
```

Note: Boost has equivalent of `std::variant`/`std::optional` for C++11.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't use Boost - the code run on low-memory embedded MCUs, but yes I had already thought of four typed options...So yes, I may not need a template after all...just trying to get my head around compile-time type identification and "branching" thereon. I will give your solution some thought.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can find implementation for your platform (or at worse, reimplement it).

Answer (score 0):

You would use it that way:

```cpp
template<typename ReturnType, typename Expected>
pair<uint32_t,ReturnType> parseInput(std::string input,std::function<void(ReturnType)> f){
    // ...

    if (std::is_arithmetic<Expected>::value){
       // ...
    } else {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Base on the `Expected` and the trait the compiler will always know which branch of the `if` it has to use for a given `Expected`, so in the resulting code there won't be any branching.

If you want to implement the trait yourself it would look like this:

```
template<typename  T>
struct is_numeric {
    static const bool value = false; // defaults to false for each type you do not specialize
};

// define it as true for an int
template<>
struct is_numeric<int> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

// define it as true for an float
template<>
struct is_numeric<float> {
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

Looking at this [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TMKqJr) you can see that `gcc` even for `-O0` optimized away the if clauses:

```
#include <iostream>


template<typename  T>
struct is_numeric {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<>
struct is_numeric<int> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

int main()
{
    if( is_numeric<int>::value ) {
        std::cout << "int is_numeric " << std::endl;
    }

    if( is_numeric<char>::value ) {
        std::cout << "char is_numeric " << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

results into:

```
.LC0:
        .string "int is_numeric "
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        jne     .L5
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 65535
        jne     .L5
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
        call    __cxa_atexit
.L5:
        nop
        leave
        ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     esi, 65535
        mov     edi, 1
        call    __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Comment: Wow! Quick response, thanks! Can it be that easy? Doesn't this the produce a runtime evaluation? I would prefer a compile-time evaluation that only produced one "branch" of the code for the correct type, since I'm going to be instantiating in many places and I want to avoid bloat!

Comment: @PhilBowles if you look at the `struct is_numeric<int>`  then you have the  `static const bool value = true;` so the `std::is_arithmetic<int>::value` has to be always `true` as it is `const`. So the compiler can resolve `if (std::is_arithmetic<int>::value){` to `if (true){` at compile time, and any decent compiler then can optimized that `if (true){` away at compile time. And as `Expected` has to be known at compile-time, the compiler can optimize any `if (std::is_arithmetic<Expected>::value){` away.

Comment: I'm learning, thanks! Your replies have made it seem a lot easier than I had been imagining. I will give that version a try. Also on second thoughts, I really only need four instantiations: one for each valid format, then my multiple sources can just call the one (or two) that they expect, so I can also avoid potential bloat that way.